# Is "human-made" an appropriate, non-gendered alternative to "man-made"?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

Surprisingly, this word returns very few "meaningful" results on Google (like texts, blog posts, articles, etc) using it. It seems to be a [new word](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/human-made). Yet, the OED gives no hits.

Is this an appropriate non-gendered alternative to man-made? For instance,

> Poverty is a human-made phenomenon.

Since it still contains the word "man", some might say it is not. Yet, to my understanding, human has a much broad meaning than just a male person.

Comment: man-made is wrong here anyway. Man-made is really for things, not states of affairs. Poverty is a phenomenon for which humans are responsible or created by humans.

Comment: For climate change "anthropogenic" is used.

Comment: I'm with @Lambie ... that this isn't a good place for "man-made" in it's generally understood meaning, let alone the gender issues.  "man-made" pretty much means "manufactured" (and I don't think that needs to be turned into "humanufactured").  For your sentence I might choice "society" or "societal", or "socially created" phenomenon .  These sorts of word choices are a matter of opinion to some degree, but at least those are my suggestions.

Comment: What exactly would be wrong with "hand-made"?

Some might complain that meant "amateurishly, as opposed to professionally" and to them I suggest first that's a very different Question and for who really wants to go there, the appropriate distinction would be between "hand-made" meaning carefully and "home-made" perhaps suggesting amateurishly.

How could "human" be usefully different from "man…"?

Comment: I'm sorry to have to point this out - doubly so after all that's gone below - and do you see no difference between what you or I or anyone here thinks, or might be persuaded to accept after lengthy, scholastic consideration, and the average person-in-the-street's idea of how 'human' is different from 'man'?

Do you truly not believe both that in this context, at least, the great majority of listeners will hear 'human' and 'man' as pretty-much interchangeable… and that that makes a clearly well-intentioned suggestion, simply self-defeating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Chris H but *artificial* is a gender-neutral way of saying *man made*, equating to *engineered* - while *man-made* itself is meant to be gender-neutral.

Can we drop questions of man-made, human-made or the sense of *mankind*, not *male person*?

In the context of this Question, trying to  differentiate between "human-made" and "man-made" says what, exactly?

Most of what it says is that we should ignore etymology and historical usage, and try to appease a few neologists by distorting the language. No! Never. Always and irretrievably appalling (IMHO).

If we need to go back to the roots of our language let's do that, and do it right now!

If anyone thinks we need to change the language to suit today's politics, why must "change" mean "distort"? Why not just "restore"?

*Man* once meant *person* and now does mean *male person* but why is that a reason to invent new terms? Why not resurrect the old meaning, rather as with Miss, Mrs, Ms?

Can we recognise *wife* isn’t opposed to *husband*; each is a contraction, one of *wifman*, one of *husbandman*?

*Husbandman* meant *person who looks after (stuff)* while *wifman* meant *person who weaves*.

See that *person*? How is that difficult?

Comment: This answer mainly consists of personal opinions and only marginally addresses the OP's question, but since this is a comment on that answer, I'll try to recover some of the validity that seems to have been stripped away form the OP's pertinent question. The word "man" has been routinely used to describe exclusively male humans for at least since the 13th century. The use and meaning of this word has not been used to "suit today's politics", much on the contrary, its use and meaning has shaped the discourse of modern politics and policies. Now, evidently, "man" has never ceased to be used...

Comment: ...in Modern English to refer, more broadly, to any human, especially in expressions as "no man's land", where no expert I know has deemed fit or necessary to change it to "human". Nonetheless, it is clear how historical usage has evolved the word and that its gender-neutrality has long been put in question. You seem to vehemently disagree with the prescriptivist nature of "a few neologists", whose solution would be (in this case) to expand organically on the nuances of language, in favor of another prescriptivist approach of pretending the manifest male connotation...

Comment: ...  of the word (and its implications) never existed and reinstate the pre-medieval meaning of the word as the only norm. Mind you, I have nothing against that strategy, it's just as arbitrary (and in my opinion, informationally worse) as any other and does not carry the virtue that you imply. To borrow an example from you, since Miss, Mrs, Mr all derive from the latin "magister", meaning leader or teacher, should we address passersby by those credentials? Thank you for taking the time to read this, Robbie.

Comment: @Bcpicao To show you what's what would mean books worth of detail, for which you'd need to go to Chat.

Sorry and your Post, not mine, is opinion. Everything I said is well-established fact, as you would know if you'd researched the issue before opining. 

Most obviously, the word 'man' has been routinely used ever since it came into English to describe any person… which is the sole point of the Question. Does anyone else doubt that?

That 'man' even might mean male exclusively arose very much later that the 13th century as you would know if you'd researched the issue.

Comment: Indeed, my post is opinion (based on the presented evidence) but so is yours (you admit it yourself). The relevant difference being yours is an answer to a question which had little to do with how our society should deal and react to the intermingling of political polarization and the natural evolution of a spoken language; mine is but a comment to said answer. It was a straightforward question which you answered well in your first sentence, but then inexplicably proceeded to ask eight rhetorical questions in a tangential rambling, which is not the norm nor the standard of this website.

Comment: I am not meaning to refute your opinion, to berate you, nor to waste both our times, just to, hopefully, further elucidate the OP and subsequent interested visitors on the topic, and also to advise them to correctly identify opinionated answers and take them with a grain of salt. You are completely entitled to the opinion you defend here, and I wish you farewell.

Comment: @Bcpicao Why not look again at what I Posted and explain in detail what you doubt about it? Can you say what might convince you it was more fact than opinion?

Answer (score 9):

This is really a matter of opinion. I'll give mine with some reasoning.

I try to be careful with gender assumptions in writing, but would still use *man-made* if a synonym such as *artificial* didn't work, as it doesn't here. This means I consider *man* in *man-made* to have the sense of *mankind* (the human race) not *male person*.

*Human-made* would not present any difficulties in understanding; however, dropping a neologism into the middle of a text does disrupt the flow of reading (in my opinion).  You could use it if you wanted to make a real commitment to gender neutrality (though there are a very few people who wouldn't like *human* as it contains *--man*; you'd probably end up with *people-made* before you could please them).

But then maybe *man* is correct in this case (poverty); look at the gender distribution of power and wealth now and historically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no gender neutral alternative to man-made, especially not human-made.  I base this solely on George Orwell's *Politics and the English Language* which has 6 advanced ninja-level rules for writing really well.  The 6th rule is: Break any of these rules sooner than say anything outright barbarous.

Human-made is barbarous.